# how to bundle systemjs.config.js of Angular2 using browserify?

Tags: angular, gulp, bundle, browserify, systemjs

I'm trying to create a bundle in my angular2 app using browserify.
I used [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git) for my project. It initially send 40 requests at starting of the project which i tried to reduce by using browserify. It worked perfectly when I created bundle of pollyfills except systemjs.
Here is my pollyfill.js which works perfectly.

```
require('core-js/client/shim.min.js');
require('zone.js/dist/zone.js');
require('systemjs/dist/system.src.js');
```

I bundled it using this command.

```
browserify pollyfill.js -o bundle.js
```

Now to bundle systemjs.config, I did following changes in config file...

```
'@angular/core': require('@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js'),
  '@angular/common': require('@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js'),
  '@angular/compiler': require('@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js'),
  '@angular/platform-browser': require('@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js'),
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'),
  '@angular/http': require('@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js'),
  '@angular/router': require('@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js'),
  '@angular/forms': require('@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js'),

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      require('rxjs'),
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': require('angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js')
```

and created bundle using this  command

```
browserify systemjs.config.js -o bundle.config.js
```

now If I include bundle.config.js than it throws 404 not found error.
[included bundle.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljHzQ.png)

please someone guide me how to solve this error?

Comment: Why can't you try https://github.com/angular/angular-cli  angular-cli to build the angular2

Comment: angular-cli uses webpack and I want to use systemjs.